# Dynamically created divs with added class don't have styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm trying to generate some divs dynamically through a for loop. They don't have the color and size styling, even though I've added a class and I can see the class in the developer tools.

```
public addDivs() {
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('test');
      div.innerHTML = 'testing'
   }
}


.test {
   color:red;
   background-color:green;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
}
```

When I add styling like this it does work.

```
public addDivs() {
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = 'testing'
      div.style.color = 'red';
   }
}
```

Is it possible (without JQuery) to get the styling from a css file?

edit: Also I should add that it started to fail only when I put the code in a for loop.

Comment: Do you import your stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, other elements work just fine. Also I should add that it started to fail only when I put the code in a for loop.

Comment: It's typescript.

Comment: Works with function

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I assume you add the divs you create to the DOM? If so please show how since others now answer that you need to add the divs

Comment: I've found the problem. It is an Angular related issue with the View encapsulation. 

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I've added  'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None' to my component decorator like this:
`@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})`

I'm still reading what the consequences are of changing this. I'm still new to Angular and stackoverflow, so sorry for the incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Append the element after creating it. Existing classes and styles works with dynamically created nodes.

```js
function addDivs() {
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('test');
      div.innerHTML = 'testing:'+i;
      document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div);
   }
}
addDivs();
```

```css
.test {
   color:red;
   background-color:green;
   height: 40px;
   width: 100px;
   margin-bottom:4px;
}
```

Comment: Of course he does: `and I can see the class in the developer tools.`